# How to explain to customer why classifier make such decision?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

In our project we use Stochastic Gradient Descent (after CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer) for classify messages The customer new in ML, so he want to understand (how) why model relates a message to some category. Could you please give suggestions for explanation, of course, without math?

Comment: SGD is not a model. If you want to explain anything, talk about the model and not the training details. If you need something explainable, use decision trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first and foremost if your customer is not from technical background , then never use technical terms in front him. by using technical terms , you are making situation even more worse because he is into new thing and he is confused with your jargon. so never make someone freak out .!!

give him simple examples :

like " Recommending music on gaana.com , saavn.com " or " Recommending Movie on NetFlix " :

tell him/her " how a machine will understand what is your like and dislike ? ". or even how you will get to know my music liking and disliking ? can you ?

by finding my favorite. right !! 
how you get to know this my favorite ? Either by asking me !! or looking into my most top rated or more liked or you heard i always listen some common songs !!

Exactly this above process you followed is called " finding pattern in Machine Learning " and using this method machine able to recommend new songs, movies, ..etc.

i'll also suggest don't explain above thing . because your customer is not that much dumb who is dealing with your work/product !!

give him real time use cases.. like recommendation process , or in social media recommending friends !!.. and many more...